# How do Vipers acquire targets?

Tags: technology, battlestar-galactica, weapon

Viper pilots don't seem to have any means of targeting Cylon raiders. In this artist's rendition we see four main components:

- The top sweeper, which is probably a short-distance radar
- Center screen, main instrument panel
- Two side-screens for auxilliary systems

[image: Viper cockpit - artist's rendition]

The top sweeper is positioned in a fabulously bad position for ergonomics. Moreover there is no HUD and the pilots don't seem to wear any helmet-mounted displays.

[image: su27 HUD]

This is the HUD of a Su-27 going guns on its target. It seems weird that even the earliest fighter biplanes had *some* way of lining up the shot so the [low-tech](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2795/25941) explanation doesn't fit. But we know that the pilots don't (always) eye-ball their targets because they can be heard saying *I can't get a lock!* quite often.

In the spinoff *[Caprica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprica_%28TV_series%29)* I remember the Viper simulation didn't have any recognisable targeting systems either (but I could be wrong). So, how do the Vipers know where to shoot?

Comment: How canon/accurate is that artist rendition?

Comment: @phantom42 I've seen vipers with components not present in the rendition but as far as the main screens go, I think it's accurate. I'm watching some episodes now to capture some good screenshots.

Comment: The "lock" could be for missiles.

Comment: I don't recall the Vipers carrying any missiles ever in the show... didn't that task fall to the Raptors?

Comment: I _think_ I've seen them fire missiles but it was only once.

Comment: I gather the HUD projects upwards onto the clear material of the canopy

Comment: @Richard That's a very good guess. I'll try to see if I can spot the projection

Comment: @eidylon The vipers carried missiles (or at least non-bullet weapons) in [The Hand of God](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/The_Hand_of_God_(RDM)).

Comment: Good point; that is a good example of when they did... though that was a special-case mission. Special armaments for SpecOps. Given their small wings, I would think even under those conditions, they could carry two missiles each. But yup, good example of when they did.

Comment: I think, to be honest, you're reading too much into the phrase, "I can't get a lock". Most of the time, Vipers are shooting simple projectiles. While their instruments may help them to aim, there really isn't any "lock" involved in the way there would be with missiles. In the end, these details were deliberately omitted by the writers because they didn't really matter. The story is not about the mechanics of dogfighting in space. It's about the people in the cockpits.

Comment: @rath: Done, then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, to be honest, you're reading too much into the phrase, "I can't get a lock". Most of the time, Vipers are shooting simple projectiles. While their instruments may help them to aim, there really isn't any "lock" involved in the way there would be with missiles.

In the end, these details were deliberately omitted by the writers because they didn't really matter. The story is not about the mechanics of dogfighting in space. It's about the people in the cockpits.